# Problem with setting up a pending intent / BroadcastReceiver

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

I want to send a notification at a certain time a day.
For this I made a BroadcastReceiver.
but I have the problem the Broadcast Receiver doesn't get executed at the times I want, instead it get executed at random times (when I start the app e.g.)
Here is the code in my main activity which sets up the pending intent and a AlarmManager:

```
        Intent notifyIntent = new Intent(this, ReminderBroadcast.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, NOTIFICATION_REMINDER, notifyIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    String notificationTime = SettingsSharedPreferences.getDailyNotificationTime(getApplicationContext());

    //sets the notification time, which is saved in Shared Preferences
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
    Calendar notificationTimeCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    notificationTimeCalendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    try {
        notificationTimeCalendar.setTime(sdf.parse(notificationTime));
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //sets AlarmManager
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, notificationTimeCalendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
    SettingsSharedPreferences.setNotificationTimeChanged(MainActivityTaskAddListNavigation.this, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup starting alarm service on device reboot.
Try below link this will help you. I implemented with same one.

https://www.stacktips.com/tutorials/android/repeat-alarm-example-in-android

Comment: I have implemented a DeviceBootReceeiver.